# how to prevent changed url in the browser bar from reflecting in the website content?

Tags: yii

how to prevent the change in the url of the browser bar from reflecting in the website content's URLS... 
here is the situation,

in my current web app, I am using this

```
$this->createUrl(Yii::app()->controller->id ."/". Yii::app()->controller->action->id, $params)
```

to generate href of the hyperlinks... now the problem is, 
when I type in the browser bar like e.g

```
www.mysite.com/blahblahblah/subcategory/c1
```

the blahblahblah, also reflects to the webpage content hyperlinks,because of the Yii::app()->controller->id that I passed to the createUrl function...any work around for this ?..., what i want to happen is, no matter what string is typed in the place of the controller name via the browser bar, it won't reflect in the webpage content hyperlinks ..

so how ?

Comment: Do you have control over the server? Usually rewrite rules can be used for this; or you use `POST` rather than `GET` to let the server know what you want.

Comment: i don't have control to the server..is there a work around for this ?, so that whatever was typed in the place of the controller id won't reflect at the web page content ?

Comment: so you want the links to be `www.mysite.com/subcategory/c1`?

Comment: based from my first post, the links are reflecting whatever was typed at the browser bar, because the `$this->createUrl()`, is having a $route  param value of `Yii::app()->controller->id . "/" . Yii::app()->controller->action->id` , so it is assuming the e.g blahblahblah that i typed, as the controller

Comment: so, any work around for this thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was, I took the ID from the URL ,created a simple Helper function and used that to return the correct value of category/subcategory and outputs it in the view source no matter what change is done via the browser bar